# How are the different kernel naming schemes relate?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, conventions

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 with the Kernel
3.8.0-030800-generic downloaded from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-raring/

When I want to run for example turbostat or cpupower commands, I get the following:

```
cpupower not found for kernel 3.8.0-030800
You may need to install linux-tools-3.8.0-030800-generic
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no package for linux-tools for this kernel available.

I noticed that there are different naming schemes for the kernels, for example, the packages for linux-tools available [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-tools-3.8.0&searchon=names) are following the naming:

3.8.0-{19-39}

whereas the version of our kernel ends in 030800.

How do these two naming schemes relate to each other? What is the correct way to install linux-tools for this kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I found some more information about this and will answer my question in case somebody comes across the same problem.

[Mainline kernels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) are used to test whether a problem was fixed by the Kernel developers, because mainline kernels are built from the latest unmodified "mainline" kernel sources. The kernel version as for example 030800 indicates a mainline kernel.

Generally, in production the kernels from the repository should be preferred. The versions for those kernels end in for example 3.8.0-{19-39}.

There is also [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels) which discusses the use of mainline kernels.

Regarding the linux-tools for mainline kernels, they will not be available on the repository, since it is not a kernel from the repository, but they can be built from the source for the corresponding mainline kernel version.